Genealogy in tikz with surrogate mother
I try to make with tikz a simple genealogical tree like this one:

Theire is only two difficulties.

Agamemnon had childs with two wifes (Cleopatra I and Cixi) ;
Helios and Selen had a child over a surrogate mother Matahari.

I tried with genealogytree but it really hard. I failed to connect Agamemnon as father of Freydis+Assurbanipal and Selen+Helios at the same time.
Questions

How to do such a tree?
Is it better to genealogytree for this purpose and use other tikz library?


My (unuseful) try
As legitimately asked by @acr, I bring here the code I had  before asking this question. As you can see, and that’s why I didn’t bring it however Stack’s rules implied it, my try is totally unusefull, since I was not able to make at least just a simple family shape.
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@m]
{
 child{
  g[male]{Agamemnon}
  p[female]{Cixi}
   c[female]{Freydis}
   c[male]{Assurbanipal}

 }
 child{
 g[male]{Hélios}
 c[female]{Séléné}
 }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Rendering


define 'better'. I tried to draw a tree with genealogytree once and cannot say my efforts were marked by success. on the other hand, I don't find it hard to believe the package can be a powerful tool in the hands of somebody who understands how to use it. If you need to draw a lot of similar trees, especially if you want to work with genealogical databases, persisting may be worthwhile. otherwise, just pick your favourite library/programme.

note that genealogical trees are not trees in the sense that term is used in mathematics/logic and tikz/pgf etc. because the latter allow only single-parent families. so fine for species which confine themselves to asexual reproduction. less fine otherwise. I'd probably use forest but a matrix of nodes is probably the most straightforward approach. you've not posted any code ....

Considering the complexity of many families, I would put one set of parents per page and hyperlink the names to othe pages.  Not sure how to do adoptions or surrogates, though.  Is it geneology if no genes are invovled?

Here is a solution using the genealogytree package. This is a very powerful and impressive package from Thomas F. Sturm, but, as said by a previous contributor, it is a huge and rather complex package, with a high learning curve. Its usage is rather straightforward for "standard" cases, but it requires time and efforts to find how to manage some special constraints, as the two ones in your example, among many other possible ones. So, if your needs are only occasional, I would also advise you to look at other solutions like the ones previously suggested.
I add references to the manual of the package (283 pages for the version 2.3.0) for the special constructs that I use. You will also need to refer to the documentation of the tcolorbox package (also from Thomas F. Sturm), which is heavily used by genealogytree (548 pages for the version 6.3.0).
Notes:

I use here 7-bits coding for accented letters for full portability but, of course, for your own usage rather use UTF-8 coding and direct insertion of accented letters.

In all standard cases, the positions and alignments are correctly computed, but in a case as your one, it is required, or simply visually better, to make some manual adjustments with the parameters parent distance in child graph, child distance in child graph, edges down by, edges up by and xshift tikz option.


\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[templates]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

% level size                     (5.3 Graph Geometry, see p. 84)
% parent distance in child graph (5.3 Graph Geometry, see p. 89)
% child  distance in child graph (5.3 Graph Geometry, see p. 87)
% edges=none                     (8.2 Edges Types, see p. 212)
% edges down by                  (8.8 Edge Shifting, see p. 233)
% edges up   by                  (8.8 Edge Shifting, see p. 233)
% union                          (4.4 Subgraph 'union', see p. 69)
% xshift tikz option             (2.5.3 Manual Position Adjustments, see p. 48)

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \genealogytree[template=signpost,
                 level size=0.6cm,
                 parent distance in child graph=0.5cm,
                 child  distance in child graph=0.5cm,
                 box={colback=white,no shadow,sharp corners}]{
    child[edges down by = 1 of 6]{% To put edges in the middle: 1/3 + 1/6 = 1/2
      p[tikz={xshift=1.2cm}]{Cl\'e{}opatre I}
      g[tikz={xshift=2cm}]{Agamemnon}
      child{
        g{S\'e{}l\'e{}n\'e}
        p[edges=none]{Matahari}
        g{H\'e{}lios}
        c{Cl\'e{}opatre II}
      }
      union[edges up by = 1 of 6]{% To put edges in the middle: 2/3 - 1/6 = 1/2
        p[tikz={xshift=2.5cm}]{Cixi}
        c{Freydis}
        c{Assurbanipal}
      }
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



welcome! Very nice answer.

You provided no code, so I don't really think I should answer this. But you can't get an 'is' from an 'ought'.
This is a sketch. It provides a structure you can modify to produce the diagram, without trying to reproduce the diagram itself. For one thing, I'm not typing all those names. For another, setting it up took too long already.
See the documentation for the matrix library to

add borders to nodes,
adjust cell spacing and appearance.

See the calc library and/or positioning for ways to

adjust the routes the lines of descendancy take.

See the pgf/tikz library for ways to

modify the appearance more generally.

Code for basic structure:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,ext.paths.ortho}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,row sep=1mm,column sep=5mm,nodes in empty cells]
  {
      & C &   & A & C \\
      &   &   &   &   \\
    S & M & H & F & A \\
      &   &   &   &   \\
      & C &   &   &   \\
  };
  \foreach \i/\j/\k in {%
    m-1-2.south/m-2-3.west/m-3-1.north,
    m-1-2.south/m-2-3.west/m-3-3.north,
    m-1-4.-110/m-2-3.west/m-3-1.north,
    m-1-4.-110/m-2-3.west/m-3-3.north,
    m-1-4.-70/m-2-4.east/m-3-4.north,
    m-1-4.-70/m-2-4.east/m-3-5.north,
    m-1-5.south/m-2-4.east/m-3-4.north,
    m-1-5.south/m-2-4.east/m-3-5.north,
    m-3-1.south/m-4-2.center/m-5-2.north,
    m-3-2.south/m-4-2.center/m-5-2.north,
    m-3-3.south/m-4-2.center/m-5-2.north%
  }
  \draw (\i) |-| (\j) |-| (\k);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


the code is roughly at the point where I would get fed up and do it in forest ....
